# How to include a file from any folder's file including include function in php

Tags: php

I have a folder named class. Here I have a lot of class.
And a folder, named include. Here I have added  `header.php` and `footer.php`
Then I have a fille called `index.php` in my project root directory. 
I have added `header.php` and `footer.php` in my `index.php` using `include_once`.
And I have included all classes in my `header.php`. So I get access all class from `index.php`.
Now I have created another folder called product. Here I have a file named `add.php`.
The problem is, when I want to access all class by including `header.php` it sayes `No such file or directory`.
So how I can get access all class by including header.php.

Comment: provide full path of that file in `include_once` like `include_once('../foldername/filename')`

Comment: Yes I have added like this. But my `add.php` file is in a different folder. So adding `header.php` is not working here. I want to make something like this, that, I can include my `header.php` from any folder without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your application folder structure but you can do certain things to get going-

1. add all folder paths in php.ini include_path variable where your classes are present
2. create a function called autoload then write the code of lazy loading in there. (search for autoload concept if you are not aware of this)
3. register the function using spl_autoload_register(autoload)

now you don't have to worry about loading all the classes itself. they will be included automatically whenever needed.

This is the best practice too.

Comment: Maybe this is the right answer for me. But I have to try first as you said. Tank you for response.